# How do I figure out how many times I have to add a short to get the value of another short?

Tags: java, math

How does one figure out how many times one has to add a short to get the value of another short?

I know, I know, it's a weirdly phrased question. But in more specifics without all the primitive types of Java...

Basically, I have a `short x`, which we'll use the placeholder `7` for. I also have a `short y`, which I'll say is the number `5`. And then, I have a `short z`, which I'll say is `236`.

Now, what I want to do, is get an `integer` that counts how many times I have to add the number `y (5)` to the number `x (7)` to get to the maximum value of `z (236)`.

Obviously, I could do that somewhat with a pencil and paper right now, but what I need is something that I can input the 3 values and it will give me the `integer` as the output - ***the number of times I have to add the value y to the number x to get to the maximum value of z.***

If you still don't understand what I'm doing, then a more visual example is:

`(Y * someint) + X = Z` How would I get to `someint`?

Comment: Looks like basic algebra.  Subtract X from both sides, then divide by Y?

Comment: Mod operator?  I don't know what it is in Java.

Comment: (Y * someint) + X = Z        |||||   (Y* someint) = Z - X                  ||||| someint = (Z - X)/Y

Comment: I thought they taught this in 6th grade or so?

Answer (score 7):

```
int result = (z - x) / y;
```

The result is `int` even if division has a remainder which is ignored in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated this is simple division. But if you're looking for other completely unnecessary ways to do this, heres a loop way...

```
public static int getNumOfAdds(short x, short y, short target){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; y*i + x  < target; i++){}
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val = (Z-X)/Y;
rem_val = (Z-X)%Y;

if (rem_val != 0)
  val++;
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively?

Try something like

```
Func(short x , short y, short z, int c) 
if ( x >= z )
return c
else
return Func(x+y,y,z,c)
```

and your first call would be Func(x,y,z,0)

Comment: Completely true, but if this is just an example of what he wanted, and what he wanted was more complex, or he is just learning recursion, and is supposed to do it recursively, this would do it.

He might be a student with a recursion project.